# PayPal(PHP): match customer with order

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using my own cart and "Aggregate cart amount" method (https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_howto_checkout_outside) with Buy Now button to pass total amount to PayPal. I also have IPN listener to verify if the order was processed which works well.

What I need is to send email to customer and to myself with order details (items, quantity, prices) from IPN when payment is verified. My cart is stored in `SESSION`, but I can also pass it to DB. Everything could work well, I am just missing the way **how to match customer with order** (without letting customer to register or login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "invoice" is not a sufficient unique identifier, you can put an arbitrary string in the "custom" field.

(By default PayPal blocks duplicate payments of the same "invoice" string.  But "custom" can be any arbitrary string.)

Comment: so custom could be solution, but how can I find out invoice identifier (do you mean txn_id?) before the information are send to paypal?

Comment: "invoice" (the invoice id) is a field you would define and set yourself for each transaction.  It is not set by PayPal the way txn_id is.

So "invoice" can work much the same as "custom".  Some differences are:

"invoice" is visible to your customers on e.g. their receipt and transaction history,  "custom" is not visible to your customers.

Each "invoice" must be unique to your account, or new transactions with the same (duplicate) invoice will (by default) be denied.  "custom" doesn't need to be a unique value in this way, it can be any string you want within some length

Answer (score 1):

1. You can identify the user with their details like email or username. But sometimes we have problem in identifying using such things and if we are doing something related to payment then we dont take any rist with it and its also not a good practice.So for the security reason the paypal provide us to pass a special parameter for identification which is **custom**. we can easily put any number of encoded parameters in this field and will get it back in response.
2. For uniquely identifying you can use the user email,username,address etc. Serialize them and post it in **custom**.